# How to schedule npm run build in Vercel (formerly Zeit Now) with Next.js app to be called every hour

Tags: next.js, vercel

My application leverages the [getStaticProps (SSG)](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#next-gen-static-site-generation-ssg-support) function (which fetches from api at build time).

I would like to npm run build every hour so that the application can fetch from api and stay up to date.

Any recommendations is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Incremental Static Regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration) worked out really well for me in similar situation. Simply add `revalidate` option to your `getStaticProps` return object.

Comment: This is a very new feature and I think it should do the job! Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend that. There are much better solutions than triggering builds.

What kind of data does it fetch from the API? and if the data you request is dynamic (other than apon build time) then I do not see why you would want to use an unintended feature.

Maybe with a little bit more explication around your use case, we could suggest a better method?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I fetch SpaceX launch schedule data from https://docs.spacexdata.com/?version=latest#5fc4c846-c373-43df-a10a-e9faf80a8b0a. Which is updated every 2 - 3 days on average. My website is https://spacex-launches.hasansefaozalp.com/

Comment: You might want to have a look at this, https://github.com/zeit/next.js/discussions/11552 i think it might interest you in your use case

Comment: Thank you that that link! That is exactly what I need, although it seems to be not implemented yet. It is at the stage of proposal as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed my app to trigger build every hour with [webhook](https://vercel.com/docs/v2/more/deploy-hooks?query=Deploy%20Hooks#) from Zeit Now and scheduling a POST request every hour with [Zapier](https://zapier.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60850836/2665655). I will add more information:

- Use SSR with a caching strategy, such as [Serverless Pre-Rendering](https://zeit.co/blog/serverless-pre-rendering).
- Use SSG to generate a basic template then an [API](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/api-routes) to fetch the required data. Caching strategies are crucial here as well:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  // fetch from external API
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 's-maxage=3600, stale-while-revalidate')
}
```